# Define varchar with variable length

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, varchar, alter-table

I am attempting to modify the datatype of a specific column in a specific table in a SQL Server 2012 database. in the beginning of the script, the user will be setting the new desired length of the column datatype. However when I attempt to alter the column in the table to set the new `varchar` length I am getting an error.

Here is the code snippet and the resulting error:

```
Declare @newPrecis int

Set @newPrecis = 23 -- New length of the index

Alter Table [dbo].[VTAB0047] Alter Column VAL varchar(@newPrecis)
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near '@newPrecis'.

Currently the length of the `VAL` column is `varchar(20)` and I'd like it to be set to a length of 23 or whatever length is inputted in the `set` statement.

I'm ignoring any type of error checking at the moment because I'm simply trying to get the basic functionality down.

Comment: You cannot use parameters for the `varchar(n)`  length - try `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VTAB0047] ALTER COLUMN VAL varchar(23)` and I'm sure it'll work just fine

Comment: Yes, I know that works and if it were viable to do it that way in the entire script, I would not be asking here. I posted a minimal example of the script; the rest of the script is several hundred lines and has nothing to do with the question specifically.

Comment: You would need to use [dynamic SQL](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/) to do this the way you're trying.  As a caveat, however, I would question the usefulness of such code.  Your schema shouldn't change so often that you need to determine the statement dynamically.  Repeatedly increasing or decreasing the size of the field is likely to cause performance problems.

Comment: ...and/or data loss.

Comment: @BaconBits - I plan on only modifying the table if certain criteria are met like: the new length is larger than original length, datatype is varchar to begin with, etc... that's why I said I'm ignoring error checking. This is for a one-off modification on a single SQL instance, but the script will be utilized across other systems on an as needed basis.

Comment: A practical note: making a `varchar` maximum length *smaller* is of very little use, so just make it large enough (plus a little) and be done with it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you want to be able to change the `length` of a `varchar column` `dynamically`  then use `dynimic sql`, because `varchar(n)` does not allow parameters for `n`:

```
declare @sql varchar(500);
Declare @newPrecis int
Set @newPrecis = 23 --or any other value 

set @sql='Alter Table [dbo].[VTAB0047] Alter Column VAL varchar('+cast(@newPrecis as varchar(2))'+')'
exec(@sql)
```

or you could directly use :

```
Alter Table [dbo].[VTAB0047] Alter Column VAL varchar(23)
```

**Note:** if your new value for `n` be less than old value then you may get `String or binary data would be truncated` error if you had value with the length greater than new value for length.

Answer (score 4):

```
Declare @newPrecis  int    
Declare @query varchar(max)

Set @newPrecis  = 23; -- New length of the index
set @query ='Alter Table [dbo].[VTAB0047] Alter COLUMN  VAL varchar('
  + Cast(@newPrecis  as varchar) +')'

 exec (@query)
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is an input parameter at the top of a script, the ALTER TABLE statement will have to be done using Dynamic SQL. For example.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @newPrecis INT

SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE dbo.VTAB0047 ALTER COLUMN VAL VARCHAR(' + CAST(@newPrecis AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')'
EXEC(@SQL)
```